# C# - textbox don't need to wait until the end?

Tags: c#, dialog, try-catch, buttonclick

I have this code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    logBox.Text += "My text";

    try
    {
        ping thing;
    }
    catch 
    { 
    }
}
```

How can I show the logBox.Text += before doing the try ? Actually, need to wait the end of the thread to show the text in my logbox...

I don't want wait the app doing the try and show directly the logBox.Text when I click on the button.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: If you want the UI thread to update before "ping thing" completes, you can't do "ping thing" on the UI thread. Do it in a Task.

Comment: `logBox.Refresh` will force a redraw. Note that empty `catch` blocks are an anti-pattern, and that long-running tasks like this should generally be done on a background thread.

Comment: Hanging the UI is an anti-pattern too.

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer ! 
Sorry but i'm begginer and... I don't understand how create a task ?! Actually, I do all my thing on an event (button click).

Comment: Any piece of code that you know is going to take at least a few seconds, should be done asynchronously so that you don't block the UI thread (you'll know when this happens because your program will freeze). Give this a read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just need that : 
Click on a button => Update my logbox (show a message in the logbox) => After UI update done, try to ping server => if ok, download and read an XML file => MessageBox.Show. 

All is working but... I see my logbox UI was updated after ping and MessageBox.Show for advertise an

Comment: @juupiter If you google "how create a task C#" you'll find out. But `Task.Run(()=> { ping thing });` will do it. I'm assuming that you understand that you'll need to replace `ping thing` with actual code that compiles.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Modify your code to following:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    logBox.Text += "My text";
    logBox.Refresh();//This will display the modifications

    try
    {
        ping thing;
    }
    catch 
    { 
    }
}
```

---

**CAUTION:**

The way this answer solves the problem is not recommended. This doesn't really make your code much responsive and the output is also not guaranteed in some edge cases. In general, it is not recommended to use the way suggested here.

Using Background Thread or Task is better way to go. The Task-way is already explained in other answer. Also, the comments under question are explaining the same.

I am copying some of the comments (as comments are second class members):

> If you want the UI thread to update before "ping thing" completes, you can't do "ping thing" on the UI thread. Do it in a Task. – 15ee8f99-57ff-4f92-890c-b56153

> ..........and that long-running tasks like this should generally be done on a background thread. – Cody Gray

> Hanging the UI is an anti-pattern too. – 15ee8f99-57ff-4f92-890c-b56153

> Any piece of code that you know is going to take at least a few seconds, should be done asynchronously so that you don't block the UI thread (you'll know when this happens because your program will freeze). Give this a read: msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx – ThePerplexedOne

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task.Factory to achieve that. Example from the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
      String[] files = null;
      String[] dirs = null;
      String docsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

      tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => files = Directory.GetFiles(docsDirectory));
      tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(docsDirectory));

      Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, completedTasks => {
                                             Console.WriteLine("{0} contains: ", docsDirectory);
                                             Console.WriteLine("   {0} subdirectories", dirs.Length);
                                             Console.WriteLine("   {0} files", files.Length);
                                          } );
   }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       C:\Users\<username>\Documents contains:
//          24 subdirectories
//          16 files
```

Just put your task creation into the event handler you are using.